# libcrypto version not found, despite version being on my system

Tags: linux-mint, encryption, openssl, libraries

I'm trying to run some software, but I am getting this error message:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by /home/jessica/project/lib/libgdal.so.20)
```

This is odd, as I have a file called `/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10`:

```
/usr/lib$ ll | grep libcrypto
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       44 Nov  7 02:03 libcrypto.so.10 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       15 Nov 18 09:15 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> libcrypto.so.10
```

I reinstalled an older version of openssl [per this site](https://github.com/91yun/serverspeeder/issues/19#issuecomment-229833865) but I still have this issue.

I am running Linux Mint 19 on a virtual machine.

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

The output of `ldd /home/jessica/project/lib/libgdal.so.20` is:

```
/home/jessica/project/lib/libgdal.so.20: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by /home/jessica/project/lib/libgdal.so.20)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff655d0000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007fa9a8db5000)
    libfreexl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreexl.so.1 (0x00007fa9a8bac000)
    libgeos_c.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos_c.so.1 (0x00007fa9a897d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa9a875e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa9a8556000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fa9a82e4000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fa9a7f23000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa9a7d06000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa9a7b02000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa9a7779000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa9a73db000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa9a6fea000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa9a6dd2000)
    libgeos-3.6.2.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos-3.6.2.so (0x00007fa9a6a39000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa9a9fef000)
    libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007fa9a6682000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fa9a645c000)
    libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007fa9a48b3000)
```

**EDIT 2**

I now have the same problem (or at least a connected one) on a different piece of software as well!

I just downloaded the `.tar.gz`, extracted it and ran `./configure`, and I get this:

```
...
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for SSL_accept in -lssl... yes
checking for BN_init in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: TORQUE needs lib crypto (often openssl-devel) in order to build
```

Comment: Is it possible to re-compile your software? It expects the version-string libcrypto.so.10 in the so-file, what does 'string /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10|grep libcrypto' show?

Comment: @stoney It's 3rd party software: I did not compile it. It is supposed to run as-is but I'm getting these errors (this is like the 5th dependency error I've had so far with this)

Comment: If you can't recompile: is the software supposed to work with mint 19 then?

Comment: @stoney It's supposed to work on any Linux distro, certainly all debian-based ones

Comment: Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985720/ncl-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libssl-so-10-version-libssl-so-10-not-found-requi which might help

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `file /home/jessica/project/lib/libgdal.so.20`.

If the output includes the word `32-bit`, then it's a 32-bit application/library and it needs a correspondingly 32-bit version of libcrypto.

First, run `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`. If it outputs nothing, you'll need to enable the 32-bit version of the x86 architecture in the package management system. That can be done with `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`. If the first command outputs `i386`, this configuration is already done.

After that, assuming that your configured repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` also include 32-bit packages, you should now be able to install a 32-bit version of `<package_name>` with commands like this:

```
sudo apt install <package_name>:i386
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install <package_name>:i386
```

and so on. Basically, just add an `:i386` suffix to the package name in your favorite package management tool.

If that is not what the problem is, please add the output of `ldd /home/jessica/project/lib/libgdal.so.20` to your post. This lists all the libraries that particular library depends on. There might be some dependency conflicts that need to be addressed.

Comment: Ok I just ran the first command line you gave me and I got this `/home/jessica/project/lib/libgdal.so.20: symbolic link to libgdal.so.20.4.0`, so i ran the same command for that file and I got `/home/jessica/project/lib/libgdal.so.20.4.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=812552bbc6850c7340d5ddcfd10d4d26c59deead, with debug_info, not stripped` - doesn't seem to be any 32s anywhere

Comment: So please add the output of the `ldd` command I suggested at the end of my answer to your original post. It will most likely be too long and hard to read if added as a comment.

Comment: I added the `ldd` output to my question